# How can I rewrite the root location of resources referenced in reverse proxy pages in Apache 2?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

We have an application server located at http://foo.bar .

It needs to be accessed via http:// wibble/foo using reverse proxying.

This I've managed, however there is stuff in http:// foo.bar which references from /

EG:

/images/blah.jpg

So it's trying to get http:// wibble/images/blah.jpg instead of

http:// wibble/foo/images/blah.jpg

Any idea how I can get it to insert the /foo prefix for anything referenced from / ?

Comment: is this http:// wibble/images/blah.jpg  comming from the html page ?

Comment: Yes, the pages refer to /images/blah.jpg so the client is requesting the file from http:// wibble/images/blah.jpg instead of http:// wibble/foo/images/blah.jpg

Answer (score 1):

mod_proxy **never** modifies the HTML.

> Only the HTTP response headers
>   specifically mentioned above will be
>   rewritten. Apache will not rewrite
>   other response headers, nor will it
>   rewrite URL references inside HTML
>   pages. This means that if the proxied
>   content contains absolute URL
>   references, they will by-pass the
>   proxy. A third-party module that will
>   look inside the HTML and rewrite URL
>   references is Nick Kew's
>   mod_proxy_html.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nginx as your front-end server, you can use the HttpSubModule to perform the substitution. Essentially, nginx should proxy the request and perform the substitution on the returned text. I do believe though, that you can't use this if you have compression on the backend (so as long as you have compression on the front-end server you should be fine):

Essentially:
Nginx -> proxy to apache -> return to Nginx -> perform substitution -> compress and serve

I presume a similar module exists for Apache and other servers.